# TensorFlow: Apply the recall metric only to binary classification?

Tags: tensorflow, precision-recall

I am experimenting with the mnist dataset and wanted to use the recall function
`tf.keras.metrics.Recall`. How is the recall applied for the mnist dataset?

Answer (score 0):

It's applied the same way as all other metrics:

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall